# Sum value for Password_Life_Time + Password_Grace_Time

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to run a query in Oracle to return the SUM of two values for each profile for `PASSWORD_LIFE_TIME` and `PASSWORD_GRACE_TIME`.
For example, if under `RESOURCE_NAME` for the `DBA_PROFILES` I have the following:

```
PASSWORD_LIFE_TIME = 5 (VARCHAR2(32))
PASSWORD_GRACE_TIME = 85 (VARCHAR2(32))
```

My expected returned value would have to be 90 (85 + 5)
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you please post what you already tried and the problems you are having?

Comment: Wh would you store numbers as character strings?

Comment: I have a feeling that the name of the column is RESOURCE_NAME that the data he posted is the whole content of the string @GordonLinoff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*According to your explanation here is a request to get the sum of the two kinds of values you specified PASSWORD_GRACE_TIME, PASSWORD_LIFE_TIME, and group them per profile :*

```
select profile,sum(to_number(limit))from dba_profiles
where ascii(substr(limit,1,1))between 48 and 57 and resource_name in  ('PASSWORD_GRACE_TIME','PASSWORD_LIFE_TIME')
group by profile;
```

Comment: thank you Walid. This query works very well. One more question... is it possible to add in this query a filter that only returns values that are higher than 90?

Comment: Yes chris: add this clause to the end: having sum(to_number(limit))>90 and also don't forget to mark my answer as accepted so others may be helped ;)

Answer (score 0):

With the very limited information you gave us.
Use `GROUP BY`.

```
SELECT profile, SUM(PASSWORD_LIFE_TIME), SUM(PASSWORD_GRACE_TIME)
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY profile
```

Comment: Adding more background:

PASSWORD_LIFE_TIME granted values based on profiles:
"DEFAULT", 84
"QUERY_1", 30
"QUERY_2", 30
"SYSTEMS", UNLIMITED
"DBA_PROFILE", 84

PASSWORD_GRACE_TIME granted values based on profiles:
"DEFAULT", 6
"QUERY_1", 5
"QUERY_2", 5
"SYSTEMS", UNLIMITED
"DBA_PROFILE", 6

Comment: "SELECT PROFILE, LIMIT FROM DBA_PROFILES WHERE RESOURCE_NAME='PASSWORD_LIFE_TIME';"

Comment: "SELECT PROFILE, LIMIT FROM DBA_PROFILES WHERE RESOURCE_NAME='PASSWORD_GRACE_TIME';"

Comment: @Christian you should edit the question to incorporate this information, instead of using comments.